# Issue with Ubuntu installation alongside pre-installed Windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10, mbr, gpt

Although I browsed through solutions to many similar problems posted previously, I still could not succeed.

The main issue is that during the installation of Ubuntu 22.04 in a USB stick (created using Rufus), the installer do not identify the Windows installation, so no option of installing Ubuntu alongside Windows is present. The following message is displayed: "This computer has no detected operating systems."

I own a Lenovo Idepad Y510p, 1 TB SSD, running Windows 10 (upgrade from Win7).

I went through all advised verifications and procedures, such as:

- Using Windows disk partition utility, shrunk Windows partition, reserving about 250 GB for the Ubuntu OS, as seen here: [Win10 - disk management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrqTT.png)
- In Win10 control panel, disabled Fast Startup.
- In BIOS, UEFI is enabled; secure boot is disabled.

In the Ubuntu terminal, launched in the desktop environment in Try Ubuntu during installation, the relevant output of `sudo fdisk -l` is:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: WDC  WDS100T2B0A
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 96EA98AE-983E-4E85-BA24-623AC01B5DAA

Device          Start       End Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    2050047 2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2   2050048 2582527     532480   260M EFI System
/dev/sda3   2582528 4630527 2048000  1000M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4   4630528 4892671     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda5   4892672 1385627647 1380734976 658.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6  1867975281 1869787760    1812480   885M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda7  1869787761 1953522288   83734528  39.9G Microsoft basic data
```

And `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.9

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sda: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Model: WDC  WDS100T2B0A
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 96EA98AE-983E-4E85-BA24-623AC01B5DAA
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 482352493 sectors (230.0 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)  End (sector)  Size      Code  Name
   1            2048        2050047   1000.0 MiB  2700  r Cópia para Partiç...
   2        2050048         2582527   260.0 MiB   EF00  
   3        2582528         4630527   1000.0 MiB  0700  
   4        4630528         4892671   128.0 MiB   0C01  
   5        4892672     1385627647   658.4 GiB   0700  
   6    1867975281      1869787760   885.0 MiB   2700  
   7    1869787761      1953522288   39.9 GiB   0700
```

Finally, the output of `gdisk` on `sda5` (NTFS Windows partition) is:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda5
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.9

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory.
***************************************************************

Exact type match not found for type code 7200; assigning type code for
'Linux filesystem'
Exact type match not found for type code 6C00; assigning type code for
'Linux filesystem'

Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
2508946357 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.
Disk /dev/sda5: 1380734976 sectors, 658.4 GiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 379908E8-D060-45AF-9DCF-9B7C6C41AE75
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1380734942
Partitions will be aligned on 32-sector boundaries
Total free space is 1380734909 sectors (658.4 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)  End (sector)  Size      Code  Name
   1    1920221984      3736432267   866.0 GiB   8300  Linux filesystem
   2    1936028192      3889681299   931.6 GiB   8300  Linux filesystem
```

Possibly the reason is the partition table overlap indicated above.

Running `fixparts` on Windows partition, the output is:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fixparts /dev/sda5
...
Problem: MBR partitions 1 and 2 overlap!
Warning: Deleting oversized partition #1! Start = 1920221984, length = 1816210284
Warning: Deleting oversized partition #2! Start = 1936028192, length = 1953653108

MBR command (? for help):
```

I am not quite sure if resizing partitions, as indicated by fixparts will solve the Ubuntu installation problem.

Given all this information, would anyone suggest me how to proceed from here?

Comment: Not sure what gdisk was showning. You run it on a drive not on a partition like sda5. You run chkdsk from Windows which you cannot run from Linux. Is Windows fast startup on? https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation  Some Lenovo's have a locked setting in UEFI. Some have "device guard" which may lock boot. Check that USB boot is allowed. Do you have latest firmware for UEFI from Lenovo?

Comment: Thanks, @oldfred. First: chkdisk did not find anything to be repaired. Second: Yes, fast startup is off. I tried running fixparts on disk sda, but the output was: `Loading MBR data from /dev/sda ...This disk appears to be a GPT disk. Use GNU Parted or GPT fdisk on it!...Exiting!`. I assumed it was because fixparts is unable to run on disks containing mbr partitions. Am I correct? Fourth: USB Boot is allowed. Fifth: Yes, I confirmed that the latest UEFI firmware available matches the one currently installed.

Comment: Do nor run fixparts on your Windows partitions. In general, do not run any commands you don't understand, otherwise you have best chances to damage an OS. Make sure to boot your Ubuntu installer in UEFI mode. Since your Windows is installed in UEFI mode, you need to install in UEFI mode to achieve proper dual boot. You should disable CSM (legacy boot) in your firmware settings to prevent booting in wrong mode.